# All fields search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, tree, mongodb-query, multi-level

This is my data set, which is part of a bigger json code. I want to write a query, which will match all fields inside the value chain.

**Dataset:**

```
"value_chain" : {
    "category" : "Source, Make & Deliver",
    "hpe_level0" : "gift Chain Planning",
    "hpe_level1" : "nodemand to Plan",
    "hpe_level2" : "nodemand Planning",
    "hpe_level3" : "nodemand Sensing"
},
```

**Example:**

If someone searches for "gift", the query should scan through all fields, and if there is a match, return the document.

This is something I tried, but didnt work

```
db.sw_api.find({ 
    value_chain: { $elemMatch: { "Source, Make & Deliver" } } 
})
```

Comment: I have made some edits in my question

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create **[`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)** index on all the text fields first since it performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with a text index:

```
db.sw_api.createIndex({
    "value_chain.category" : "text",
    "value_chain.hpe_level0" : "text",
    "value_chain.hpe_level1" : "text",
    "value_chain.hpe_level2" : "text",
    "value_chain.hpe_level3" : "text"
}, { "name": "value_chain_text_idx"});
```

The index you create is a composite index consisting of 5 columns, and mongo will automatically create the text namespace for you by default if you don't override it. With the above, if you don't specify the index name as

```
db.sw_api.createIndex({
    "value_chain.category" : "text",
    "value_chain.hpe_level0" : "text",
    "value_chain.hpe_level1" : "text",
    "value_chain.hpe_level2" : "text",
    "value_chain.hpe_level3" : "text"
});
```

there is a potential error `"ns name is too long (127 byte max)"` since the text index will look like this:

```
"you_db_name.sw_api.$value_chain.category_text_value_chain.hpe_level0_text_value_chain.hpe_level1_text_value_chain.hpe_level2_text_value_chain.hpe_level3_text"
```

Hence the need to give it a name which is not too long if autogenerated by mongo.

Once the index is created, a `db.sw_api.getIndexes()` query will show you the indexes present:

```
/* 1 */
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "dbname.sw_api"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "value_chain_text_idx",
        "ns" : "dbname.sw_api",
        "weights" : {
            "value_chain.category" : 1,
            "value_chain.hpe_level0" : 1,
            "value_chain.hpe_level1" : 1,
            "value_chain.hpe_level2" : 1,
            "value_chain.hpe_level3" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 3
    }
]
```

---

Once you create the index, you can then do a **[`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)** search:

```
db.sw_api.find({ "$text": { "$search": "gift" } })
```